# How to show meta attributes on survey plot in Orange (Data Mining)

Tags: plot, orange, meta-attribute

I am using Orange 2.7.8 and would like to display display a certain Meta-attribute next to each series on a Survey plot.

Is there an option to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not supported in Survey Plot.